# Find repeated attribute patterns in collection of objects

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, algorithms

I have objects $o_1,...,o_k$where every object has a set of properties $p_1,...,p_j$. I'm looking for property *patterns* that are repeated among these objects. It could be perhaps called *correlation* of properties. I'm interested in what properties occur most often together on an object.

Example input:

$o_1 = \{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$
$o_2 = \{p_1,p_3,p_4\}$
$o_3 = \{p_1,p_2,p_4\}$

Expected output:

$\{p_1,p_2\}$ present in objects $\{o_1,o_3\}$
$\{p_1,p_3\}$ present in objects $\{o_1,o_2\}$
$\{p_1,p_4\}$ present in objects $\{o_2,o_3\}$

It will be common to have about $20-30$ properties on every object and hundreds/thousands of objects.

I'm definitely not a math expert but if you tell me what kind of algorithm/what data structures can be best used for this kind of stuff (or even if this problem has a well known name) then I'd be grateful.

Comment: What answer would you want given your example?

Comment: @gung As I said in the last sentence ... what kind of algorithm/data structure can be used for this. And what would be the steps to process the data in the best way to achieve the expected output. e.g. 1. Take the properties, dump it in some tree structure 2. In every node save the number of references to something, ... 13. Go through the tree and every  node with > 2 references will be part of the result.

Comment: No algorithm can be specified without a goal being specified. What would be `whatever_algorithm`'s correct answer given your example input?

Comment: @gung What I mentioned in the example is the expected output. Another example would be: Input: o1={"a", "b", "c"}, o2={"b", "c", "d"}, o3={"a", "b", "d"}; Output = {"a", "b"} in {o1, o2}

Comment: @gung I edited the question to include the example input/output. You're right that it wasn't clearly specified.

Comment: That helps, thanks. You want lists of objects that correspond to combinations of patterns. So, along with your input data, are you going to input a list a patterns that you care about, or do you want lists of objects for every possible combination of patterns? (Be prepared for a combinatorial explosion with the latter.)

Comment: Unfortunately I need the latter.

Comment: I don't know where you took that from nor how I could use that:(

Comment: You're right, I used the wrong function (it seemed way too small). The correct answer is that you will have $1,\!073,\!741,\!823$ lines of output from your algorithm to scroll though. Eg, you start w/ $30$ patterns $\{p_1\}, \{p_2\},\ldots,\{p_{30}\}$, & end w/ 1 pattern $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_{30}\}$. In between, there are $1,\!073,\!741,\!792$ patterns (eg $435$ patterns of size $2$ in a set of $30$ items. Even if you have only $20$ properties, you would still have $1,\!050,\!777,\!736$ lines of output to read through. You may want to input a manageable list of patterns you care about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you want to find so-called association rules. You can find these quite effectively using a technique called association rule learning. Have a look at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning

Comment: I found an Apriori algorithm implementation that's mentioned on the page you linked (among many others) and it seems to find only correlation of pairs of properties. Like if set contains A, then it 65% contains also B. Do you have any concrete algorithm that could provide me with the results I mentioned in the question?

Comment: A more detailed overview http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/ch6.pdf

Comment: So my idea would be that you enter all the bins in the {} format into the apriori algorithm. It will then produce rules with all kinds of combinations of objects and properties. Say it may find {o1, o2} -> {p1, p2} but also {o1, p3, p2} -> {p4}. This is not wat you want, but you can post-process these rules by keeping only the rules which are of the form {p} -> {o}. Then after that you can combine the rules which have the same {p} to obtain the type of rules that you are looking for. In the comment above I provided you with a link to a detailed explanation of the concept

Comment: Apriori implementations are readily available, and the only processing that you would need to do yourself is the post-processing on the produced rules (i.e. selecting only those which fit your format), and combining them by looking whether their left or right hand side is the same (which can be done by simple comparison)